# Remove content between HTML tags in PHP?

Tags: php, html, dom

I would like to remove all content (between tags) from a HTML string.
Is there an elegant way to do this without writing complex regex?

If you want, I am actually looking for the *opposite* of what `strip_tags()` does.

Suggestions?

Comment: Or try this https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solution uses regex. I will let you decide if it is complex or not.

```
$out = preg_replace("/(?<=^|>).*?(?=<|$)/s", "", $in);
```

Let's break it down:

- `(?<=^|>)`: A lookbehind. Not actually matched, but it still has to be there. Matches either beginning of string (`^`) or literal `>`.
- `.*?`: Matches anything (`s` modifier makes it include newline). The question mark makes it lazy - it matches as few characters as possible.
- `(?=<|$)`: A lookahead. Matches either literal `<` or end of string (`$`).

This is replaced by nothing (`""`), so that everything between `>` and `<` is deleted. A working demo can be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/fJ7qC6/1). It does not preserve whitespace, so you end up with one super long line.

**EDIT:** If you know that your input will always be wrapped in HTML-tags you can make it even simpler for yourself, since you don't have to think about the beginning and end of string bits:

```
$out = preg_replace("/>.*?</s", "><", $in);
```

This variant will not work for input with text at the beginning or the end - for instance `Hello <b>World</b>!` will become `Hello<b></b>!`.